Can proof by contradiction be used disprove a statement?
I'm currently taking an introductory proofs class. The textbook that we are using justifies proof by contradiction by stating that the statement $P$ is logically equivalent to the statement $(\neg P\implies(Q\land\neg Q)).$ The logic makes sense to me when we use the proof technique conventionally as follows: assume that $\neg P$ is true and then prove that $Q\land\neg Q$ is also true; therefore, the implication is true and thus the statement $P$ is true by logical equivalence.
However, can proof by contradiction be used to prove that $P$ is false? I encountered a problem when disproving $P.$ I'm having a bit of a hard time understanding the logic behind the proof technique.
Let $P$ be the statement '$1=1$' and $Q$ be the statement '$1\not=2$'. Assume $\neg P$ is true (that is, assume that $1\not=1),$ and clearly $Q\land\neg Q$ is false, so $\neg P\implies (Q\land\neg Q)$ is false, and by logical equivalence $P$ is also false.
Now, I have proved that the statement $P$ is false by using a proof by contradiction. Clearly, a problem has arisen, since $P$ is not false.
What is wrong with my above argument?

If you want to prove that $P$ is false, define $R =\neg P$. Now you have to prove $R$ is true (by contradiction or by any other method)


Let $P$ be the statement '$1=1$'.
Assume $\neg P$ is true (that is, assume that $1\not=1)$

Okay; let's call this Assumption (1).

and clearly $Q\land\neg Q$ is false, so $\neg P\implies (Q\land\neg Q)$ is false, and by logical equivalence $P$ is also false.

Yes.

I have proved that the statement $P$ is false.

No, your proof is arguing that $$\lnot P\implies(\lnot P \Longrightarrow \bot)\text{ is false}\implies P\text{ is false}.$$ You have merely proven that under Assumption (1), statement $P$ is false; in other words, you have proven this: $$1\ne1\implies (1=1\text{ is false}).\quad✅$$
This conclusion obviously isn't illuminating or useful; nonetheless, your proof is entirely valid (coherent).

Clearly, a problem has arisen, since $P$ is not false.

No problem has arisen, because you have not actually proven this:
$$1=1\text{ is false}.$$

However, can proof by contradiction be used to prove that $P$ is false?

Sure, proof by contradiction can soundly disprove a false statement.
Let $P$ be $1=2.$
Assume, for the sake of contradiction, that $\boldsymbol P$ is true.
Now, since $1<2,$ we have that $1\ne2.$
Therefore, we have the contradiction $1=2$ and $1\ne2.$
Hence, our assumption must be false: $\boldsymbol P$ must in fact be false.

Reply to comment

Thanks for you response! I see your point that everything I have proven is under assumption (1), which leads to an unsound argument.

Your argument/proof is actually sound, as that assumption $\color\red{1≠1}$ is not a genuine premise, since it was eventually discharged by becoming the antecedent of the proof's tautological conclusion $$\color\red{\lnot P}\implies (P\text{ is false}).\quad✅$$

I've noticed that the first step for any proof by contradiction is to assume ¬P is true. Then we prove that P is true, is that under the assumption ¬P is true as well?

No: by the end of the proof by contradiction, the assumption $¬P$ will also have been discharged. In Structure of a Proof by Contradiction, I explained that such a proof is implicitly premised on the logical entailment $$\color{green}{(\lnot P\implies \bot)}\implies P,\tag{*}$$ which is why (and how) the meat $$\color{green}{\lnot P\implies \bot}\tag{#}$$ of the proof logically implies (and allows us to finally conclude) that $P$ must in fact be true.
Side note: while sentence $(*)$ is true regardless of $P$'s truth, sentence $(\#)$ is true only if $P$ is actually true. That is to say, proof by contradiction isn't ever able to prove a false statement or disprove a true statement.

The textbook that we are using justifies proof by contradiction by stating that the statement $P$ is logically equivalent to the statement $(\neg P\implies\bot).$

To be precise: proof by contradiction doesn't actually depend on the full equivalence $$(\neg P\implies\bot)\color\red\iff P,$$ only its forward direction $(*).$

Thanks for you response! I see your point that everything I have proven is under assumption (1), which leads to an unsound argument. However, in a slightly different direction... I've noticed that the first step for any proof by contradiction is to assume $\neg P$ is true. Then we prove that $P$ is true, is that under the assumption $\neg P$ is true as well?

@LearningMath I've expanded the answer; glad to help!

$2(1-1)=(1-1)$. By your logic, since $1\neq1$, then $(1-1)\neq0$, so $2=1$. Since $2 \neq 1$, Implication true, hence $1=1$.
